# I can't send data to the server c++11

Tags: sockets, c++11, server, client

I am a beginner at the socket programming level that's why I found some problems that may be simple. I tried to send a simple message from client to server but the command send `return (-1)` that's why the message not received by the server.

Also, I have the same problem in the server code and the receiver command.  `return (-1)`.

Following is my client code :

```
bool ClientSock() {
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in address;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(10102);



if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof (address)) < 0) {
    cout << "connect failed. Error \n";
    return 0 ;
} else
    return 1;
}

void SendComm() {

long ok;
    char MESSAGE [2000];
    string msg;
    cout << "enter message:\t";
    cin>> msg;
    const char * s = msg.c_str();
    int sock;
    ok = send(sock, s, 1024, 0);`enter code here`
    if ( send(sock,s,1024,0)< 0){//this is the problem
    std::cout << "you can not send the message";
}
    else{
    ok = recv(sock, MESSAGE, sizeof (MESSAGE), 0);
    string reply;
    reply = MESSAGE;
    cout << "server says:_t" << reply << endl;
}
}

int main() {
if (ClientSock()==1){
     SendComm();
}
else 
    std::cout << "error";

 }
```

This is my server code:

```
bool initialize() {
int conSock;
int ListenSock;
socklen_t addrsize;
struct sockaddr_in address;
addrsize = sizeof (address);

conSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(10102);
ListenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(ListenSock, (sockaddr *) & address, sizeof (address));
listen(ListenSock, SOMAXCONN);

std::cout << "server waiting for connexion\n\n ";


if (conSock = accept(ListenSock, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrsize) < 0) {
    cout << "connect failed. Error";
    return 0;
} else
    return 1;
}

void Communicate() {

int conSock;
int ListenSock;
struct sockaddr_in address;
socklen_t addrsize;

long ok;
char MESSAGE[2000];
ok = recv(conSock, MESSAGE, sizeof (MESSAGE), 0);
if (recv(conSock, MESSAGE, sizeof (MESSAGE), 0)< 0){
    std:: cout << "No message" ;  
}
else{
string msg;
msg = MESSAGE;
cout << " client says:\t" << msg << endl;
string reply;
cout << "enter reply:\t";
cin>> reply;
const char* s = reply.c_str();
ok = send(conSock, s, 1024, 0);
}}

int main() {

if (initialize() == 1) {
   Communicate();

} else
    std::cout << "error ";
}
```

Comment: You are using unintialized `sock` - handle of socket while sending/receiving. You should use `sock` created in `ClientSock`, not to create new one e.g. in `SendComm`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. As it looks like right now, that's a lot of code. Please post a [mcve], with emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: in the ClientSocket function I tried to create the socket and then connected with the server and in the Send Common function, I used the same socket "sock" .I did not create another socket. I do not see the exact fault

Comment: There are similar problems in the server.  'ConSock' is redeclared, and so used uninitialized, in 'Communicate()'.  Return it from 'initialize()' and pass it in as an argument.  What are you doing here with declarations?  It does not make sense:(